# How to set Apache mod_wsgi with php in httpd-vhosts.conf?

Tags: php, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to set mod_wsgi with php in httpd-vhosts.conf using same domain and port(443). Below is httpd-vhosts.conf settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ctest.lock.com:443
    DocumentRoot "/home/service/card"
    Alias /card "/home/service/card"
    <Directory "/home/service/card">
       Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mime_module>
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' .html
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ctest.lock.com:443

    #mod-wsgi : webtest
    WSGIScriptAlias /webtest /home/service/was/webtest/app.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess webtest processes=4 threads=4 display-name=%{GROUP}
    <Directory /home/service/was/webtest/ >
        WSGIProcessGroup webtest
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`https://ctest.lock.com/card` is ok, but `https://ctest.lock.com/webwas` is 404 not found. How to set?

Comment: Move the mod_wsgi stuff into the first ``VirtualHost`` with the other stuff.